# traversing a tree in two different columns in sqlite using python

Tags: python, sqlite

My sqlite database has two columns named child and parent , any element with value 0 will be root of the tree , 
Sample data:

```
child  parent
33     16
16     0
45     39
30     0
```

I am trying to write a sqlite query to determine number of trees & its path as shown below 
number of trees : 2

```
0 16 33
0 30 49
```

I am able to find out the rows with 0s ...but not able to think of a logic to generate the path..

Any suggestions please

Comment: You will have to make a separate SQL query for each non-leaf tree node with this representation. If you can, consider a [nested-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) representation or [closure tables](http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html) that allow you to fetch an entire tree with one query.

Comment: Can a parent have more than one child?

Answer (score 0):

How many children can have a parent? In your example, you seem to assume each 'root' parent has exactly one child. Maybe you could start with something like:

```
SELECT A.parent, A.child, B.child FROM mytable AS A JOIN mytable AS B
  ON A.child = B.parent WHERE A.parent = 0;
```

(not tried). But you really should be more precise in your question.

If you are interested by the number of trees, maybe something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from mytable WHERE parent = 0;
```

Best regards.

Comment: In dataset i am working number of child element is chaging .. ranging from 2 to 6